# How to create a Mixin Enum

Tags: python, enums, mixins, pathlib

I'm trying to create an enum with a `pathlib.Path` mixin, MCVE:

```
import enum, pathlib
class Test(pathlib.Path, enum.Enum):
    path1 = pathlib.Path('/path1')
    path2 = pathlib.Path('/path2')
```

which gives a totally cryptic error:

```
      1 import enum, pathlib
----> 2 class Test(pathlib.Path, enum.Enum):
      3     path1 = pathlib.Path('/path1')
      4     path2 = pathlib.Path('/path2')

File ~/anaconda3/envs/main/lib/python3.9/enum.py:288, in EnumMeta.__new__(metacls, cls, bases, classdict, **kwds)
    286         enum_member._value_ = value
    287 else:
--> 288     enum_member = __new__(enum_class, *args)
    289     if not hasattr(enum_member, '_value_'):
    290         if member_type is object:

File ~/anaconda3/envs/main/lib/python3.9/pathlib.py:1082, in Path.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
   1080 if cls is Path:
   1081     cls = WindowsPath if os.name == 'nt' else PosixPath
-> 1082 self = cls._from_parts(args, init=False)
   1083 if not self._flavour.is_supported:
   1084     raise NotImplementedError("cannot instantiate %r on your system"
   1085                               % (cls.__name__,))

File ~/anaconda3/envs/main/lib/python3.9/pathlib.py:707, in PurePath._from_parts(cls, args, init)
    702 @classmethod
    703 def _from_parts(cls, args, init=True):
    704     # We need to call _parse_args on the instance, so as to get the
    705     # right flavour.
    706     self = object.__new__(cls)
--> 707     drv, root, parts = self._parse_args(args)
    708     self._drv = drv
    709     self._root = root

File ~/anaconda3/envs/main/lib/python3.9/pathlib.py:700, in PurePath._parse_args(cls, args)
    695         else:
    696             raise TypeError(
    697                 "argument should be a str object or an os.PathLike "
    698                 "object returning str, not %r"
    699                 % type(a))
--> 700 return cls._flavour.parse_parts(parts)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/main/lib/python3.9/enum.py:429, in EnumMeta.__getattr__(cls, name)
    427     return cls._member_map_[name]
    428 except KeyError:
--> 429     raise AttributeError(name) from None

AttributeError: _flavour
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues going on here -- one is that when you mix in a class, the contents for the member definition line should be the mixin's arguments; in other words, instead of

```
    path1 = pathlib.Path('/path1')
```

you should have

```
    path1 = '/path1'
```

At this point you hit the second issue, which is found in the `Path` implementation:

```
    if cls is Path:
        cls = WindowsPath if os.name == 'nt' else PosixPath
```

and `cls` is `Test`, so neither `WindowsPath` nor `PosixPath` is chosen.

The easiest solution for that is to inherit from `WindowsPath` or `PosixPath` beforehand, and use that in the enum header:

```
BasePath = pathlib.WindowsPath if os.name == 'nt' else pathlib.PosixPath
class Test(BasePath, enum.Enum):
    path1 = '/path1'
```

and in use:

```
>>> Test
<enum 'Test'>

>>> list(Test)
[<Test.path1: PosixPath('/path1')>]
```

---

Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.